# Alternative to RavenDB Studio?

Tags: ravendb

First of all: This is not opinion based, because I do not ask about "the best", but "any" alternative way to access a ravenDB.

I have a server which uses NServiceBus and RavenDB 2 as a database. Onto this server I cannot install silverlight, so the studio is not working. I also can not upgrade to ravendb 3 to get a html5-studio. (I will do that in future, but I need a fast solution on a productive system without causing downtime).

Is there any other windows tool available that allows me to access the ravenDB?

Comment: It might not be opinion based, but it asks us to find or recommend a tool or software library, which is also off-topic here according to the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all just HTTP, so you can access the studio from another computer.  You may need to update your Windows Firewall settings to allow access.